# In scala shapeless, is it possible to use literal type as a generic type parameter?

Tags: scala, shapeless, dependent-type

Assuming that I'm writing a program for vector multiplication. Following the requirement in this article:

https://etrain.github.io/2015/05/28/type-safe-linear-algebra-in-scala

The multiplication should only compile successfully if the dimension of both vectors are equal. For this I define a generic type `Axis` that uses a shapeless literal type (the number of dimension) as the type parameter:

```
import shapeless.Witness

trait Axis extends Serializable

case object UnknownAxis extends Axis

trait KnownAxis[W <: Witness.Lt[Int]] extends Axis {

  def n: Int

  def ++(that: KnownAxis[W]): Unit = {}
}

object KnownAxis {

  val w1 = Witness(1)
  val w2 = Witness(2)

  case class K1(n: Witness.`1`.T) extends KnownAxis[w1.type]
  case class K2(n: Witness.`2`.T) extends KnownAxis[w2.type]

//  K2(2) ++ K1(1) // doesn't compile

  K2(2) ++ K2(2)
}
```

So far so good, the problem however appears when I try to generalise it for all n:

```
  case class KN[W <: Witness.Lt[Int]](n: W#T) extends KnownAxis[W]

  KN(1)
```

The above code triggers a compilation error:

```
Axis.scala:36: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: this.T
[ERROR]   KN(1)
[ERROR]      ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

My question is: why Spark is incapable of focusing on the more refined type `` Witness.`1`.T ``, instead it is using type `Int`? What does it take to override this behaviour so case class `KN` can be successfully defined?

**UPDATE 1:** The follow up has been moved to a new question:

[When using the singleton type feature of Scala shapeless, how to force the compiler to use narrow/singleton type as an implicit parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60592107/when-using-the-singleton-type-feature-of-scala-shapeless-how-to-force-the-compi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't surprising that Scala can't infer `W` given `W#T`, because generally speaking it's possible for two different `W`s to have the same `W#T`. Not for witness types, but they aren't treated specially by the compiler.

What I expected to work (and not sure why it doesn't) is to specify the type parameter:

```
KN[Witness.`1`](1)
// error: type arguments [scala.this.Any] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [W <: shapeless.this.Witness.Lt[scala.this.Int]]
```

or more likely

```
KN[w1.type](1)
// error: type mismatch;
// found   : scala.this.Int(1)
// required: .this.T
```

What does work:

```
case class KN[W <: Witness.Lt[Int]](w: W) extends KnownAxis[W] {
  val n = w.value
}

KN(Witness(1))
```

It seems to suit the requirements in your question, but I don't know if it'll work with the rest of your code.

You may also want to consider this alternative which doesn't require Shapeless in Scala 2.13:

```
trait Axis extends Serializable

case object UnknownAxis extends Axis

trait KnownAxis[W <: Int with Singleton] extends Axis {

  def n: W

  def ++(that: KnownAxis[W]): Unit = {}
}

case class KN[W <: Int with Singleton](n: W) extends KnownAxis[W]

KN(1)
```

For 2.12

```
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._

...
KN(1.narrow)
```

Comment: That was very informative, I wonder if I can make .narrow an implicit invocation

Comment: I don't know, but I'd be a bit surprised if you can.

Comment: On the other hand, doesn't `Witness.apply` do this somehow? You may want to look at its definition.

Comment: No it doesn't :-< Just tried, implicit signature doesn't work on duck typing, including Lt/Aux pattern

Comment: OK, actually implicit signature 'somehow works' with a magnet pattern, but Witness.Lt is not a strong enough constraint. I've updated my question to see if a circumvention is available in 2.12

Comment: On second thought, I'll move the update into a new question so I can accept your answer.

Comment: Probably you meant ``KN[Witness.`1`.T](1)`` although this doesn't work either.

Comment: No, `Witness.``1``.T` is clearly the wrong type (then you'd get `n: Witness.``1``.T#T`). (Don't know how to escape ` properly in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

Try to parametrize `KnownAxis` with a singleton subtype of `Int`

```
trait KnownAxis[N <: Int] extends Axis {
  def n: N
  def ++(that: KnownAxis[N]): Unit = {}
}

case class K1(n: Witness.`1`.T) extends KnownAxis[Witness.`1`.T]
case class K2(n: Witness.`2`.T) extends KnownAxis[Witness.`2`.T]

case class KN[N <: Int](n: N)(implicit w: Witness.Aux[N]) extends KnownAxis[N]

import shapeless.syntax.singleton._
KN[Witness.`1`.T](1.narrow)
```

or just

```
KN[Witness.`1`.T](1)
```

Or with abstract class instead of trait

```
abstract class KnownAxis[N <: Int](implicit w: Witness.Aux[N]) extends Axis {
  def n: N
  def ++(that: KnownAxis[N]): Unit = {}
}
```