# When using the singleton type feature of Scala shapeless, how to force the compiler to use narrow/singleton type as an implicit parameter?

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless, dependent-type

This is a follow-up of one of my previous questions:

[In scala shapeless, is it possible to use literal type as a generic type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60481612/in-scala-shapeless-is-it-possible-to-use-literal-type-as-a-generic-type-paramet)

I'm trying to write scala code for vector multiplication, while using shapeless to make the compiler aware of the dimension of each vector:

```
trait IntTypeMagnet[W <: Witness.Lt[Int]] extends Serializable {

  def witness: W
}

object IntTypeMagnet {

  case class Impl[W <: Witness.Lt[Int]](witness: W) extends IntTypeMagnet[W] {}

  implicit def fromInt[W <: Int](v: W): Impl[Lt[W]] = Impl(Witness(v))

  implicit def fromWitness[W <: Witness.Lt[Int]](witness: W): Impl[W] = Impl(witness)
}

trait Axis extends Serializable

case object UnknownAxis extends Axis

trait KnownAxis[W <: Witness.Lt[Int]] extends Axis {

  def n: Int

  def ++(that: KnownAxis[W]): Unit = {}
}
```

Ideally the implicit `fromInt` can deduce `v.narrow` (Witness can only work on final, singleton type), yet it doesn't behave as so:

```
  object Attempt1 {

    case class KN[W <: Witness.Lt[Int]](magnet: IntTypeMagnet[W]) extends KnownAxis[W] {

      val n = magnet.witness.value
    }

    // looking good, works as intended
    KN(1) ++ KN(1)
    KN(Witness(1)) ++ KN(2)
    KN(Witness(1)) ++ KN(Witness(2))

    val v1_simple: KN[Lt[Int]] = KN(1)
    KN(1) ++ KN(2) // should break
    KN(1) ++ KN(Witness(2)) // should break
  }
```

The last 2 lines doesn't cause any compilation error, which contradicts my hypothesis. Is there a way to change this behaviour such that KN created using `fromInt` can find the correct type? I'm using scala-2.12 so the singleton type of shapeless seems to be the only option.

Comment: If you follow my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60660294/5249621 you'll have: ``KN[Witness.`1`.T](1) ++ KN[Witness.`1`.T](1)`` compiles, ``KN[Witness.`1`.T](1) ++ KN[Witness.`2`.T](2)`` doesn't compile.